# Testing connection to docker daemon

Tags: linux, docker

I am writing a script that will boot docker-compose automatically.

However, sometimes, doing `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"` doesn't cause the docker daemon to be connected immediatly and when the next line comes (`docker-compose up`) I get `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?`

If I use `sleep` for a few seconds the issue resolves.

Is there a way to test the connect to daemon via some system tool (checking if a process exists, if a network connect was made, port listened to, etc)? I want to test the docker daemon externally and not use `docker` cli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Docker Remote API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.22/) has a [PING endpoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.22/#ping-the-docker-server). You can use the endpoint to check whether you can successfully connect to the Docker daemon. `docker-machine env` sets the environment variable `DOCKER_HOST`, so you can use `DOCKER_HOST` as host to ping. Using `nc`, you can ping the host as follows:

```
$ eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
$ echo -e "GET /_ping HTTP/1.1\r\n" | nc $DOCKER_HOST
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Docker/1.10.2 (linux)
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2016 07:05:58 GMT
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

OK
```

You will need to check the return value. If it returns 'OK', the connection was successful. A simple check could look as follows (this probably needs more refinement):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(echo -e "GET /_ping HTTP/1.1\r\n" | nc $DOCKER_HOST | tail -n 1)" == 'OK' ] ; then
  echo "You are connected"
fi
```

Comment: What's the Windows version of this? (i.e. checking using Windows tools; comandline, powershell, etc.)