# Conncetion to docker daemon on remote host

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have two VM's (A and B) with Ubuntu and docker installed on both. They are placed in the same virtual network. I want to access the docker daemon of A from B.

To achive this I bound the daemon of A to port 2375. To do this I added

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/docker
```

to `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` and

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
```

to `/etc/default/docker`

On B I use `docker -H=192.168.71.129:2375 run hello-world` and get the `docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon...` error.

### Troubleshooting

Iptables are disabled on both machines.

```
sudo docker -H 192.168.71.129:2375 run hello-world
```

on `A` works.

`sudo netstat -tunlp | grep docker` on `A` outputs

```
tcp6       0      0 :::2375               :::*                  LISTEN      10363/docker
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35764746) post I saw that the docker rest API has a ping endpoint. If I call this endpoint from `B` with `echo -e "GET /_ping HTTP/1.1\r\n" | nc 192.168.71.129 2375`, I get a `200 OK` code. So the Enpoint is definitive up.

Can you give me a hint why my Docker client on `B` cannot connect to the daemon on `A`?

### FYI

IP `A` `192.168.71.129`

IP `B` `192.168.71.128`

```
user@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

At `A`

```
user@ubuntu:~$ docker -H 192.168.71.129:2375 version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:47:50 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:47:50 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

At `B`

```
user@ubuntu:~$ docker -H 192.168.71.129:2375 version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:47:50 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was fine except the proxysettings... Docker uses the systemproxy to connect to the the IP's

Comment: what was the solution then?

Comment: the standard `export https_proxy=http://server-ip:port/` see https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-proxy-environment-variable/ for more